# file_exists returns false even when the file exists in my yii php application

Tags: php, yii, file-exists

[image]

I have read so many questions which bear the same title as mine, but none of them has helped me..

Above image is the output of the following function..

```
foreach (  $products as $product) {

            $file = Library::getCatalogUploadPath().$product['image'];
            echo $file.'<br>';
            if( file_exists($file)){
                echo  $file;
            }
            else {
                echo "no".'<br>';
            }

          }
```

And Here is the function getCatalogUploadPath()...

```
public function getCatalogUploadPath()
    {
        return Yii::app()->params['config']['document_root'].Yii::app()->params['config']['upload_path'].'catalog/';
    }
```

**and Here is the 'config'..**

```
'config' => array(
            'site_url' => 
            'http://l/git/cart.git/',//example:http://www.cartnex.org/
            'document_root' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],
            'upload_path'=>'git/cart.git/uploads/',
            )
```

**PROOF THAT THE FILE EXISTS :**

[image]

Comment: Where is file extension ?

Comment: Yeah, right click that puppy (haha) and see the full name in properties.

Comment: @DanMiller, You guided me in the right direction.. :)

Comment: @DanMiller Please answer the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filename `$product['image']` is malformed. It doesn't contain file extension, which is why `file_exists()` returns `false`